# Javascript: Is it possible to have a function that is automatically fired when an Object/String... created?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, orientation, magic-methods

the question is straight forward. Just like in PHP we have the magic function `__construct()`, is there any related function or hack I can use in javascript?

Example:

```
function setLength() {
    /* Some work */
}

var a = new Object();
b = new String("Hello");
//Is there anyway the function setLength() will automatically be fired when an Object or String... created?
```

I'm looking forward to your answers. Thank a lot for any help.

[x]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to overload `String` would be a **bad idea**, especially if working with third party libraries. Same would go for augmenting `Object`.

However, here is how you may do it, but I don't recommend it..

```
var _String = String;

window.String = function() {
        setLength();
        return new _String(arguments[0]);
}
```

This obviously won't be called when creating a primitive string too.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMFxY/).

---

You could use a *string factory* function that returns a new `String` object and calls your function.

```
var stringFactory = function(chars) {
    setLength();
    return new String(chars);  
}
```

This has some advantages, mainly the `String` constructor is not overloaded.

Comment: +1, for the stringfactory.  However, I don't think the first part is really a viable approach.  but, even so I would suggest using a closure to avoid creating that `_String` global variable, like `window.String = (function(){var _String = String;setLength();return new _String(arguments[0]); })();`

Comment: Thank you Alex, this until now have been the most perfect solution. I've tried to avoid it if I can. So basically when we copy/clone the String constructor and assign it to another variable then reuse it, it makes no bad effect right? [x]

Answer (score 1):

You can just create your own object by doing something like this. The function acts as the constructor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var instance = new object('test123');

    alert('Instance: '+instance.len);

    function object(var1){
        this.var1 = var1;

        this.len = this.var1.length;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi. It is a good way, I've thought of it, but I'd like to add the functions to the native Object instead of create a new one. [x]

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can override `string.prototype.constructor` to alter the default functionality of the string constructor, and `object.prototype.constructor` to alter the default functionality of the object constructor.</strike>

However, overriding the default functionality of JavaScript's core classes is widely considered to be bad practice, and there is likely a better way to accomplish your end goal.

If you do decide to do this, you might also benefit from reading the following SO Post about overriding a function with a function that references the overridden function:  [Overriding a JavaScript function while referencing the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original)

After messing around with jsFiddle, and then doing some research.  I found out that I'm actually wrong.  String primitives are immutable, so you can't override the constructor, as I suggested.  Check out [String prototype modifying itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615256/string-prototype-modifying-itself), for more info on that.

Comment: I am thinking that I would not replace the whole String construction, but instead inject some code into it, such as to know which function(s) is activated when a String is created, then we can only override that function. Is it possible? Do developers have any hack around this problem? I am just curious. [x]

Comment: How would you achieve this by modifying the `constructor` property?

Comment: @xx3004, It doesn't seem like there is going to be a way to do what you are describing.  Your best bet is to use a consistent `stringFactory` pattern to create strings like in the end of @alex's example